# Ag grid tree data

Tags: angular, ag-grid

> I have an ag grid with tree data which filters out from the view the
>   rows which are deleted

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"test",
      "children":[  
         {  
            "name":"test",
            "ROWSTATE":"DELETE"
         },
         {  
            "name":"test",
            "ROWSTATE":"DELETE"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

> this is my data and the filter configuration is like this

```
isExternalFilterPresent: () => { return true; },
            doesExternalFilterPass: (node: RowNode) {
        return node.data.ROWSTATE !== ROWSTATE.DELETE;
    }
```

> The grid doesn't display any value because all the chilrens does not
>   pass the filter function I suppose. What I want to do is to make the grid to 
>   show the row which contains the parent.

Comment: Can we see it in a plunker?

Answer (score 1):

This also happens to me. What I did as a workaround was to modify my `getNodeChildDetails` function on the gridOptions, in a way such that it checks if all children are deleted. If they all are, then don't return anything. That way, ag-grid won't consider the row as a parent row.

```
var gridOptions = {
    ...
    getNodeChildDetails: function(row) {
        if (row.children) {
            for (var i = 0; i < row.children.length; i++) {
                if (row.children[i].ROWSTATE != 'DELETED') {
                    return {
                        group: true,
                        expanded: true,
                        children: row.children
                    };
                } 
            }
        } 
    },
    ...
};
```

This is inefficient, since it has to iterate through all the children to check if all of them are deleted. However, it is a workaround that works.

Don't forget to add the group cell renderer to the column that will be in charge of the expansion and contraction of the children:

```
var columnDefs = [
    ...
    {
        headerName: ...
        cellRenderer: 'group'
    }
];
```

Of course, this applies to whichever framework, either pure javascript or angular.